# Generated a list of filenames, but no file paths

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list box that displays a set of filenames that reference text files. I think it is aesthetically unappealing to display full paths, so I used `Path.GetFileName` to cut off the directory part.

But now when the user selects a particular filename to open, I've lost the paths. The files could be located anywhere on the local computer (for now).

How can I use the list box so that I can display nice filenames, but also have reference to the actual file?

EDIT: I like the idea of having a custom wrapper class for each list box item.

Comment: What happens if there are two files with the same FileName but in different Paths? How will the user know to select one or the other?

Comment: Cross your fingers and hope for the best. I'll provide an option to show full paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's I've done in the past is create a wrapper class for the objects I want to display in the ListBox.  In this class override `ToString` to the string you want to display in the ListBox.

When you need to get details of a selected item, cast it to the wrapper class and pull the data you need.

Here's an ugly example:

```
class FileListBoxItem
{
    public string FileFullname { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() {
        return Path.GetFileName(FileFullname);
    }
}
```

Fill your ListBox with FileListBoxItems:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(new FileListBoxItem { FileFullname = @"c:\TestFolder\file1.txt" })
```

Get back the full name of a selected file like this:

```
var fileFullname = ((FileListBoxItem)listBox1.SelectedItem).FileFullname;
```

---

**Edit**
@user1154664 raises a good point in a comment to your original question: how would a user differentiate two ListBox items if the displayed file names are the same?

Here are two options:

**Also display each FileListBoxItem's parent directory**

To do this change the `ToString` override to this:

```
public override string ToString() {
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(FileFullname);
    return string.Format(@"...\{0}\{1}", di.Parent.Name, di.Name);
}
```

**Display a FileListBoxItem's full path in a tooltip**

To do this drop a ToolTip component on your form and add a `MouseMove` event handler for your ListBox to retrieve the `FileFullname` property value of the `FileLIstBoxItem` the user is hovering the mouse over.

```
private void listBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    string caption = "";

    int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
    if ((index >= 0) && (index < listBox1.Items.Count)) {
        caption = ((FileListBoxItem)listBox1.Items[index]).FileFullname;
    }
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(listBox1, caption);
}
```

Of course you can use this second option with the first.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/894d0814-dcf1-4cd6-9cca-2c6239794442/) for the ToolTip in a ListBox (the accepted answer, code reformatted to a flavor I prefer).

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListBoxItem.Tag` to store the full path for each item if using WPF.  Or, if using WinForms, you can create a custom class that stores the full path, but overrides object.ToString() so that only the filename is displayed.

```
class MyPathItem
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);
    }
}

...

foreach (var fullPath in GetFullPaths())
{
    myListBox.Add(new MyPathItem { Path = fullPath });
}
```

Comment: I hate it when people start using the Tag property as their personal crap bucket. I have seen code fail lots of time because of a lack of discipline with that property, it's an old fashioned practice left over from days when there was no other option.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't agree with you sentiment that this is ugly for the user. Showing the full path gives the explicit details to the user and enable them to have confidence in their selection or what ever they are doing.

I would use a `Dictionary`, using the item index as the Key and the full path of this list item as the value.

```
Dictionary<int, string> pathDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
pathDict.Add(0, "C:\SomePath\SomeFileName.txt");
...
```

The above is probably the best way to go here over using the `item.Tag` property...

I hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I could always provide an option for showing or hiding the directory paths in case the user prefers them.

Answer (score 1):

I do this

```
public class ListOption
{
   public ListOption(string text, string value)
   {
      Value = value;
      Text = text;
   }

   public string Value { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then create my list

```
List<ListOption> options = new List<ListOption>()
For each item in files
   options.Add(new ListOption(item.Name, item.Value));
Next
```

bind my list

```
myListBox.ItemSource = options;
```

Then get my value or text

```
protected void List_SelectionChanged(...)
{
   ListOption option = (ListOption) myListBox.SelectedItem;
   doSomethingWith(option.Value);
}
```

Just the idea here is main thing